# Using Pickle.dump() to Save a PKL file to an Object

Tags: class, object, pickle, dump

I am trying to save a pkl file to an object M of the class obstacle_struct() using pickle.dump(). The line of code in question is:

```
pickle.dump(M,open('RRT_Models.pkl','wb'))
```

I am getting the following error:

"pickle.dump(M,open('RRT_Models.pkl', 'wb'))
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '**main**.obstacle_struct'>: attribute lookup obstacle_struct on **main** failed"

Any input is highly appreciated.